# What are the strange property types generated in a C# anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

Observe the following trivial anonymous type in C#

```
new { X = 5 };
```

The respective compiler generated code as seen in Reflector (omitting the object method overrides) is:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
internal sealed class <>f__AnonymousType0<<X>j__TPar>
{
    // Fields
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly <X>j__TPar <X>i__Field;

    // Methods
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <>f__AnonymousType0(<X>j__TPar X)
    {
        this.<X>i__Field = X;
    }

    // Properties
    public <X>j__TPar X
    {
        get
        {
            return this.<X>i__Field;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is WOE (What On Earth) is `<X>j__TPar`? The type is reflected nowhere in Reflector (pun intended).

Comment: Ok, see: [Why are anonymous types generic?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic.aspx) by Eric Lippert

Comment: The names contain angle brackets too so that they can never legimitely be called from C# code (angle brackets are illegal in names in C# but not in IL). See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx

Comment: @Henk: Great link! I'll upvote if you add this as an answer. :)

Comment: @Henk: Why didn't you add it as an answer?

Comment: Stupid me, missed that it is the generic argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<X>j__TPar` is the name of the generic argument used in the `<>f__AnonymousType0` type definition. A bit less readable indeed than `T` but guaranteed to never collide with another name.

Comment: Stupid me, missed that it is the generic argument.